# Images not rendering in Chrome/Webkit

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit

I'm building a webpage with a bunch of images that are all coming from Rackspace Cloudfiles on their Limelight CDN. Occasionally the page will finish loading, including the images, and Chrome/Webkit will fail to render some images at all.

Chrome doesn't render a "broken image" in their place, and if I check the Resources tab in the Inspector, they are listed and the data is all loaded up. The non-rendered images show the same info as the properly rendered ones.

This usually occurs when I go forward a page and then go back (via history). It persists if I reload the page, unless I do a hard refresh (⌘⇧R in Chrome), then they all show up like normal again.

I'm not loading the images in JavaScript or anything strange like that, nor do I have any CSS that hides the images. This only happens in Chrome, and it doesn't happen in Incognito mode from what I can tell.

Any ideas what's causing this? If it's a bug, how do I go about reporting it to the Chrome team?

#### Update

I checked the headers in the Network tab of the Inspector and it turns out that for the images that are rendered, Chrome is only showing it's header metadata, like this:

[image: Headers]

And for the images that *don't* render properly, the metadata is shown along with the full request and response headers with a `304 Not Modified` status.

---

#### This is still happening. On multiple computers, on several websites. There's a [thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=59edeb170358baff&hl=en) about this happening over the Google support forums as well.

Comment: That is pretty weird, I'm guessing it has something to do with the cache. Have you tested your page in another computer? idk just what first comes to my mind.

Comment: if that doesn't happens in incognito mode, then thats definitely cache.

Comment: When the images are not shown, are their Content-Types proper? I wonder if this is something to do with load balancing of the CDN occasionally hitting some misconfigured servers...

Comment: That's what I figured, especially given that a hard refresh fixes it. Still, I'm not familiar enough with the innards of Webkit/Chromium to know whether this is just something in my environment (corrupted cache file or an extension causing problems) or if it's a bug that needs to be reported.

Comment: This is definitely a cache issue. What they (Limelight) are doing is setting the Expires header to a very long time (like  one year out).

Comment: @Shiv Actually, the expires header is set according to what you set it at via Rackspace CloudFiles. Mine are 1hr on development, and 72hrs on production.

Comment: @Ates: No luck. The content-type is reported as image/jpeg on all of them. They are all showing status as `(from cache)` in the network tab of the inspector, though.

Comment: Have you tried using a cache breaker like `src="image.jpg?3424"`?

Comment: @Ates No. The images are static, and while many caching systems won't cache requests with a query string, I believe Chrome et al properly cache it according to the headers, irrespective of the presence of a query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Chrome bug that has since been resolved. It is *not* the bug linked to by thatmarvin.

Comment: Do you have any more details about the bug/resolution?

Comment: @Dave Unfortunately not; I never found a relevant bug report filed, but determined that this was resolved by observation only.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a Chrome/Webkit bug:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20960

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with thumbs images using the latest chrome. Images were rendering time to time. I changed  image style:

```
width: 150px; height: 100%;
```

to

```
width: 150px; height: auto;
```

And "height: auto" has fixed bug in Chrome. 
Hope the founded solution will help in some cases.